# Compressed HTML in Laravel still contains whitespace

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am using the below code to compress HTML output in Laravel; I put it in the filters/App::after function

```
if (App::Environment() != 'local') {
    if ($response instanceof Illuminate\Http\Response) {
        $output = $response->getOriginalContent();

        // Clean comments
        $output = preg_replace('/<!--([^\[|(<!)].*)/', '', $output);
        $output = preg_replace('/(?<!\S)\/\/\s*[^\r\n]*/', '', $output);
        // Clean Whitespace
        $output = preg_replace('/\s{2,}/', '', $output);
        $output = preg_replace('/(\r?\n)/', '', $output);
        $response->setContent($output);
    }
}
```

But with character "à" I get this symbol: � instead. I tried to remove the line:

```
$output = preg_replace('/\s{2,}/', '', $output);
```

It fixed the symbol error, but the HTML output does not work perfectly (some white space was not removed). Can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you have the `mbstring` php extension enabled?

Comment: Please show the input, the output and the expected output. A minimal example of course.

Comment: Also it seems inefficient to compress the response on every request. If you're using blade views, it would make sense to compress the contents when the view is compiled using `Blade::extend()` (see more in [Laravel Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/templates#extending-blade)).

Comment: The mbstring php extension is enabled.

Comment: Hello , You need to see my library https://github.com/vrkansagara/LaraOutPress which contain all type of compression there.